# Why the absolute value in the little-$o$ notation?

Tags: complex-analysis, absolute-value

In the definition of an holomorphic function, it is said that one way of seeing this is by the existence of a variable $l$ (namely $f'(z_0)$) such that :
$f(z) = f(z_0) + l(z-z_0) + o(|z-z_0|)$

If I recall correctly, this notation is equivalent to this one :

$\frac{f(z) - f(z_0) - l(z-z_0)}{|z-z_0|} \xrightarrow[z\to z_0]{} 0$

But that yields $sgn$ functions everywhere, doesn't it ?

I wonder if the module in the little-$o$ notation is neccessary ? And also what information does it give ?

Can one write : $f$ is holomorphic if one can find an $l\in\mathbb{C}$ such that  $f(z) = f(z_0) + l(z-z_0) + o(z-z_0)$ ?

If I remember well, this kind of notation (with the absolute value) is present in real analysis too.

Comment: Some definitions of little o-notation require the function within the 'o' to be [strictly positive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation).

Comment: @PeterForeman That makes sense, the absolute value (or modulus) is only there to ensure that the difference $z-z_0$ is positive. Thus both sides are positive and the notation is legit.

Comment: Of course, $u\to 0$ iff $|u|\to 0$, so the absolute value bars in both numerator and denominator are irrelevant

Comment: @MPW You are saying that the modulus in the definition is kinda irrelevant too ?

Comment: @AlanSimonin : No, just mean that convergence to zero is the same either way